# Discord bot - Ignore command if word not present

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, bots

I'm very new to python and i'm making a discord bot for my server and for fun. I have a command that reacts to a message if it contains the word "thought". But this command makes all the others not work.

I was trying to ignore this command if the user message does not have that word, but with no success.

My code for that command is this right now:

> ```
> @bot.event
> async def on_message(message):
>     if 'thought' in message.content:
>         emoji = '\U0001F64F'
>         await message.add_reaction(emoji)
>     else:
>         if 'thought' not in message.content:
>             print('Thought is not contained in the message!')
> ```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've made your own on_message method, you must take responsibility to tell it to process the commands that may be in the message at the end of it with this:

```py
await bot.process_commands(message)
```

You can choose to place this depending on how you want to the bot to work i.e. inside the else statement would only process commands if the message doesn't include 'thought'.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 'thought' in message.content.lower():
        await message.add_reaction('\U0001F64F')
    else:
        print('Thought is not contained in the message!')
```

By calling the `str.lower()` method, the condition will evaluate to `True` regardless of case. I also removed the `if` statement inside the `else` statement because it is unnecesary.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your response!

Changed the code but it does the same thing. It detects that the word in not present and prints the "Warning" and all other commands do not work.

I was trying to add a line of code that determines if the word is not present just supress this bot event. I don't know if I'm explaning myself correctly.